# Using the \cite command in RevTex 4.2 to list multiple papers in a single reference in the bibliography output

Tags: bibtex, citing, overleaf, revtex

I am using Overleaf to write a paper for publication in an American Physical Society (APS) journal. I wish to use the \cite command in RevTex 4.2 to list multiple papers in a single reference in the bibliography output using the following syntax:

\cite{paper1, *paper2, *paper3, *paper4}

The problem is that if any of these papers has been previously cited as a key for bibtex in the manuscript, this does not work correctly and the citations get scrambled. I believe I have also downloaded all of the necessary packages (e.g. natbib).

Any guidance would be most appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Without a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), it is most likely that no one will be able to help you. Please provide some minimal compilable code that allows people to reproduce your error and find a solution.

Comment: Don’t understand the desired output. Do you want a paper to appear twice in the bibliography? First, from when it’s first cited, and second, as part of a combined citation when it’s cited as part of a group?

Comment: Let us say I have several papers in my bibliography which are defined by the keys: paper1, paper2, paper3,... What I want to do at some point in the draft is to use cite all of these papers in a single reference. According to the RevTex 4.2 Author's Guide the way to do this is to use the following command as the appropriate place in the draft: \cite{paper1, paper2*, paper3*,...}. It does not work correctly when one of these papers has been previously cited in the draft.

Comment: the observed and desired output are still really unclear to me. Try to improve your question and you will be more likely to get an answer

Comment: Dear Innisfree, The message by Danielhmm on October 26, 2015 is exactly what I am trying to do. You replied to him with a comment on that same day. Do you have a proposed solution? Thanks, Steven